# How to create an event that calls the registered listener as soon as it's registered if event was already invoked? (C#)

Tags: c#, events

I want to create a special sort of delegate in my program which upon listener registration to it, I want to check if it's already been called, and if so - immediatley call the subscribing listener.

Looking at it atomically I was able to achieve it using the following:

```
private bool _wasEventCalled;
private event Action _someEvent;

public event Action SomeEvent
{
    add
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // If already called, call immediatley
        if (_wasEventCalled)
        {
            value(this);
            return;
        }
        _someEvent += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        if (_someEvent == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        _someEvent -= value;
    }
}


private void InvokeEvent() 
{
    _wasEventCalled = true;
    _someEvent.Invoke();
}
```

This works just fine, but I'm looking for a way to create a generic event which I can reuse - since this is a lot of code to write every time I want to use this behavior.

Comment: `_someEvent.Invoke();` should be `_someEvent?.Invoke();` to handle the case where there are no handlers.  Also, this code doesn't work properly if multiple threads are calling it; presumably that's not a situation you need to handle and there is only ever one thread acting on this object at a time.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Servy it was semi-pseudo-code - my question is more on how I can achieve this in a reusable way if I want to have this behavior occur on multiple events, and thread safety isn't an issue

Comment: is removing handles something that you actually need?

Comment: @Servy if that is what prevents me from achieving this, I can live without the removal of handlers

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is more or less the behavior of `Task` continuations, so you can just piggyback onto `Task`.

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> someEventSource = 
    new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

public event Action SomeEvent
{
    add
    {
        someEventSource.Task.ContinueWith(t => value?.Invoke());
    }
    remove
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


private void InvokeEvent()
{
    someEventSource.TrySetResult(true);
}
```

Of note, tasks don't really support removing handlers, so you'd need to write your own class if that was important for you to have.

Comment: Now I see why you asked that, while that would work - We are working with Unity3d, which uses an old version of .NET (no tasks). Plus, I wanted to stay with the += convention of delegates

Comment: @Ron Then you'll need to create your own class.  It wouldn't be hard, basically just refactoring out each operation into its own method, using the implementations you already have.

Comment: so I did that as well, overloading the + and - operators. My problem with this approach is that : 1. This requires instancing the class 2. The event can get invoked from anywhere since it's a class now and not an event delegate 3. MSVS's intellisense doesn't play well with this solution

Comment: @Ron All you need to do is create a class with a `Add`, `Remove` and `Invoke` methods, create a private instance in this class, and call the relevant methods in the event add/remove handlers.  Yes, you still want to have an `event`, just refactor the implementation out to another class.